# Filename as Measure in PowerBI

Tags: button, dynamic, powerbi, filepath, measure

I am trying to create a dynamic title for a dashboard that shows the name of that file. I will use a button and the "fx" option for dynamic Button Text.

E.g. a file saved under "C:\Users\xyz\Product A.pbix" would show the button text "Product A".

Is there a way to get the file name into a measure or another way to display it using fx?
Alternatively, is there a way to grab the name of the data source?

(Reason is I will have multitude of dashboards and will already need to change the filename... would prefer to not also have to change each title manually).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get Data --> Folder and select your files localation.

By doing that, a table with all your file names and other stuff will be loaded.
Then you just have to clean the table and create the measure that select the file name.